# Highstock: export CVS/XML only visible/selected range

Tags: highcharts

I'm facing a problem when import Highstock. I'd like to import csv/xml in a highstock graph.
It's work fine but is getting the total of data present in chart. I'd like to **export CVS/XML only visible/selected range.**

Here what I found in Highstock forum:
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=41056

jsfiddle: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j01e9xtb/)

The example in JSFiddle works but is getting an number in Unix Timestemp.

```js
var defined = Highcharts.defined,
            each = Highcharts.each,
            pick = Highcharts.pick,
            win = Highcharts.win,
            doc = win.document,
            seriesTypes = Highcharts.seriesTypes,
            downloadAttrSupported = doc.createElement('a').download !== undefined;

Highcharts.Chart.prototype.getDataRows = function (multiLevelHeaders) {
            var time = this.time,
                csvOptions = (this.options.exporting && this.options.exporting.csv) ||
                    {},
                xAxis,
                xAxes = this.xAxis,
                rows = {},
                rowArr = [],
                dataRows,
                topLevelColumnTitles = [],
                columnTitles = [],
                columnTitleObj,
                i,
                x,
                xTitle,
                // Options
                columnHeaderFormatter = function (item, key, keyLength) {
                    if (csvOptions.columnHeaderFormatter) {
                        var s = csvOptions.columnHeaderFormatter(item, key, keyLength);
                        if (s !== false) {
                            return s;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!item) {
                        return 'Category';
                    }

                    if (item instanceof Highcharts.Axis) {
                        return (item.options.title && item.options.title.text) ||
                            (item.isDatetimeAxis ? 'DateTime' : 'Category');
                    }

                    if (multiLevelHeaders) {
                        return {
                            columnTitle: keyLength > 1 ? key : item.name,
                            topLevelColumnTitle: item.name
                        };
                    }

                    return item.name + (keyLength > 1 ? ' (' + key + ')' : '');
                },
                xAxisIndices = [];

            // Loop the series and index values
            i = 0;

            this.setUpKeyToAxis();

            each(this.series, function (series) {
                var keys = series.options.keys,
                    pointArrayMap = keys || series.pointArrayMap || ['y'],
                    valueCount = pointArrayMap.length,
                    xTaken = !series.requireSorting && {},
                    categoryMap = {},
                    datetimeValueAxisMap = {},
                    xAxisIndex = Highcharts.inArray(series.xAxis, xAxes),
                    mockSeries,
                    j;

                // Map the categories for value axes
                each(pointArrayMap, function (prop) {
                    var axisName = (
                        (series.keyToAxis && series.keyToAxis[prop]) ||
                        prop
                    ) + 'Axis';

                    categoryMap[prop] = (
                        series[axisName] &&
                        series[axisName].categories
                    ) || [];
                    datetimeValueAxisMap[prop] = (
                        series[axisName] &&
                        series[axisName].isDatetimeAxis
                    );
                });

                if (
                    series.options.includeInCSVExport !== false &&
                    !series.options.isInternal &&
                    series.visible !== false // #55
                ) {

                    // Build a lookup for X axis index and the position of the first
                    // series that belongs to that X axis. Includes -1 for non-axis
                    // series types like pies.
                    if (!Highcharts.find(xAxisIndices, function (index) {
                        return index[0] === xAxisIndex;
                    })) {
                        xAxisIndices.push([xAxisIndex, i]);
                    }

                    // Compute the column headers and top level headers, usually the
                    // same as series names
                    j = 0;
                    while (j < valueCount) {
                        columnTitleObj = columnHeaderFormatter(
                            series,
                            pointArrayMap[j],
                            pointArrayMap.length
                        );
                        columnTitles.push(
                            columnTitleObj.columnTitle || columnTitleObj
                        );
                        if (multiLevelHeaders) {
                            topLevelColumnTitles.push(
                                columnTitleObj.topLevelColumnTitle || columnTitleObj
                            );
                        }
                        j++;
                    }

                    mockSeries = {
                        chart: series.chart,
                        autoIncrement: series.autoIncrement,
                        options: series.options,
                        pointArrayMap: series.pointArrayMap
                    };
                
                    // Export directly from options.data because we need the uncropped
                    // data (#7913), and we need to support Boost (#7026).
                
                    each(series.options.data, function eachData(options, pIdx) {
                        var key,
                            prop,
                            val,
                            name,
                            point;

                        point = { series: mockSeries };
                    
                        series.pointClass.prototype.applyOptions.apply(
                            point,
                            [options]
                        );
                    
                    if (point.x >= series.xAxis.min && point.x <= series.xAxis.max) {
                      key = point.x;
                      name = series.data[pIdx] && series.data[pIdx].name;

                      if (xTaken) {
                          if (xTaken[key]) {
                              key += '|' + pIdx;
                          }
                          xTaken[key] = true;
                      }

                      j = 0;

                      // Pies, funnels, geo maps etc. use point name in X row
                      if (!series.xAxis || series.exportKey === 'name') {
                          key = name;
                      }

                      //console.log(point)
                      if (!rows[key]) {
                          // Generate the row
                          rows[key] = [];
                          // Contain the X values from one or more X axes
                          rows[key].xValues = [];
                      }
                      rows[key].x = point.x;
                      rows[key].name = name;
                      rows[key].xValues[xAxisIndex] = point.x;

                      while (j < valueCount) {
                          prop = pointArrayMap[j]; // y, z etc
                          val = point[prop];
                          rows[key][i + j] = pick(
                              categoryMap[prop][val], // Y axis category if present
                              datetimeValueAxisMap[prop] ?
                                  time.dateFormat(csvOptions.dateFormat, val) :
                                  null,
                              val
                          );
                          j++;
                      }
                    }

                    });
                    i = i + j;
                }
            });

            // Make a sortable array
            for (x in rows) {
                if (rows.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                    rowArr.push(rows[x]);
                }
            }

            var xAxisIndex, column;

            // Add computed column headers and top level headers to final row set
            dataRows = multiLevelHeaders ? [topLevelColumnTitles, columnTitles] :
                [columnTitles];

            i = xAxisIndices.length;
            while (i--) { // Start from end to splice in
                xAxisIndex = xAxisIndices[i][0];
                column = xAxisIndices[i][1];
                xAxis = xAxes[xAxisIndex];

                // Sort it by X values
                rowArr.sort(function (a, b) { // eslint-disable-line no-loop-func
                    return a.xValues[xAxisIndex] - b.xValues[xAxisIndex];
                });

                // Add header row
                xTitle = columnHeaderFormatter(xAxis);
                dataRows[0].splice(column, 0, xTitle);
                if (multiLevelHeaders && dataRows[1]) {
                    // If using multi level headers, we just added top level header.
                    // Also add for sub level
                    dataRows[1].splice(column, 0, xTitle);
                }

                // Add the category column
                each(rowArr, function (row) { // eslint-disable-line no-loop-func
                    var category = row.name;
                    if (xAxis && !defined(category)) {
                        if (xAxis.isDatetimeAxis) {
                            if (row.x instanceof Date) {
                                row.x = row.x.getTime();
                            }
                            category = time.dateFormat(
                                csvOptions.dateFormat,
                                row.x
                            );
                        } else if (xAxis.categories) {
                            category = pick(
                                xAxis.names[row.x],
                                xAxis.categories[row.x],
                                row.x
                            );
                        } else {
                            category = row.x;
                        }
                    }

                    // Add the X/date/category
                    row.splice(column, 0, category);
                });
            }
            dataRows = dataRows.concat(rowArr);

            Highcharts.fireEvent(this, 'exportData', { dataRows: dataRows });

            return dataRows;
        };



var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    navigator: {
        series: {
            includeInCSVExport: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 32, 221, 123, 321, 322, 29, 177, 76, 46, 245, 122, 67],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 36e5
    }],

    exporting: {
        csv: {
            dateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'
        }
    }

});

document.getElementById('getcsv').addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert(chart.getCSV());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 300px; margin-top: 2em"></div>


<button id="getcsv">Alert CSV</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.
Just include this condition inside of export-data in funciton Highcharts.Chart.prototype.getDataRows:

```js
(...)
point = { series: mockSeries };
          series.pointClass.prototype.applyOptions.apply(point, [options]);
          key = point.x;
          name = series.data[pIdx] && series.data[pIdx].name;
          j = 0;
if (point.x >= series.xAxis.min && point.x <= series.xAxis.max) {// ***this condition
      if (!xAxis || series.exportKey === "name" || (!hasParallelCoords && xAxis && xAxis.hasNames && name)) {
      key = name;
   }
(...)
}
```

If don't want change the lib following this example in fiddleJs
[example Highstock period time export](http://jsfiddle.net/stembrino/pw7bjdhu/10/#save)